# Read Barrcode using python without pressing a button

Tags: python, camera, kivy

i'm trying to build an app mobile that scan barrcode of a product , i search on the net and i found the code , but the code include 2 buttons (start camera , and read barrcode) , but i only want to read barrcode without pressing any button , so i have to delete those buttons and when the code run i must see only camera , and when i show her a barrcode  , she must read barrcode without pressing a button , 
this is the code:

````
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from pyzbar import pyzbar
import cv2

Builder.load_string('''
<BottomAppBar@Screen>:
    name: "bottom app bar" 
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: dp(10)
        orientation: "vertical"   
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Start Camera'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Read Barcode'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press : root.capture()



''')


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):

        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))

        #decode barcode from captured image and add result on top of it

        image = cv2.imread("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        barcodes = pyzbar.decode(image)
        for barcode in barcodes:
            (x ,y ,w ,h) = barcode.rect
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+y), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            #decoded barcode
            barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
            barcodeType = barcode.type
            text = "{}({})".format(barcodeData, barcodeType)

            cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            print("barCode is %s"%text)
            cv2.imshow("image", image)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()```
````

Comment: As an idea - I'd try to take image from camera each defined amount of time (1 second maybe) with export_as_image() function, so the app won't save and load images but just take it. Kivy has schedule_interval function for periodically calling functions. So then you can just check if there's a barcode on that image, if it's there - you got it, if it's not - just continue.

Comment: i really didn't undertand you , cn you please show me how,  by updating my code !!